# map with a lambda function that accepts two parameters

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I would like to fetch i'th element from all the sub lists in a list of lists.I tried using map and lambda function as below

```
extract = lambda x,i :x[i]
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]]
b = list(map(extract(i = 1),a))
```

I expect b to be [2,5,7]
but I know the last line doesn't work. How should I approach this with map and lambda

Comment: Note that naming a `lambda` is considered bad form - if it isn't anonymous, use a proper `def`.

Comment: As per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): "Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do not** need to hard code the index.

IMHO, you should return a lambda function from `extract` method by doing something like this perhaps:

```
def extract(i):
    return lambda x : x[i]

a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]]

b = list(map(extract(1), a))

print(b)
```

Output:

```
[2, 5, 7]
```

Note: Better(read pythonic) approach will be to use list comprehension like this:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]]

b = [li[1] for li in a]

print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hard code in the `1`:

```
extract = lambda x: x[1]
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]]
b = list(map(extract,a))

print(b)
# [2, 5, 7]
```

You normally don't want to store a `lambda` to a variable, this is better:

```
def extract(x):
    return x[1]

b = list(map(extract, a))
```

Or simply this:

```
b = list(map(lambda x: x[1], a))
```

You can also use a list comprehension, which I personally think is the best option:

```
c = [x[1] for x in a]

print(b == c)
True
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe I realize that, but I was trying to keep as much code from the original question as possible. I'll edit.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't spotted it was in the question too; I've moved the comment.

Answer (score 2):

The *underlying* problem is your first function argument needs to be specified when you call `extract`. This is possible via [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
b = list(map(partial(extract, i=1), a))  # [2, 5, 7]
```

But this is relatively inefficient, since a new function is created for each iteration of `a`. Instead, as others have advised, use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter
b = list(map(itemgetter(1), a))          # [2, 5, 7]
```

As an aside, [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) advises against naming `lambda` functions; define explicitly instead:

```
def extract(x, i):
    return x[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) here to fetch the second item of each sublist:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]]

print(list(map(itemgetter(1), a)))
# [2, 5, 7]
```

Or using `lambda`:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]]

print(list(map(lambda x: x[1], a)))
# [2, 5, 7]
```

Your anonymous function:

```
extract = lambda x,i :x[i]
```

Needs to instead map specifically an index:

```
extract = lambda x: x[1]
```

Then you can simply map this function to your list with `map(extract(1), a)`.

Answer (score 0):

I also vote for the 'for' solution. 
Functional programming syntax looks beautiful but its too much overhead sometimes.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]]
b = list(map(lambda x: x[1], a)) #  Brr, how many types conversions involved
c = [x[1] for x in a] # Looks more lightweight
```

Lets just check:

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit('a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]]; b = [x[1] for x in a]', number=10000)
> 0.01244497299194336
timeit.timeit('a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]]; b = list(map(lambda x: x[1], a))', number=10000)
> 0.021031856536865234
```

2 times slower.